# possible to do this as a one-liner in Ruby or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that does a lot of JSON parsing (ie using strings as keys rather than symbols).

I have the following code:

```
ad_source_ids = []
logged_one['migrated'].each { |mig| ad_source_ids << mig['id'] }
```

I'd like to do

```
ad_source_ids = logged_one['migrated'].map(&:id)
```

but don't think I can. What is an alternative? I'd like to removed the `ad_source_ids` tmp variable.

Comment: one way is `ad_source_ids = logged_one['migrated'].map {|mig| mig['id'] }`

Comment: BTW, you can use `JSON.parse(some_json_str, symbolize_names: true)` to get symbols instead of strings as keys. source: https://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
ad_source_ids = logged_one['migrated'].collect { |mig| mig['id'] }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `collect` is an alias for `map` and (anecdotally) most Ruby developers prefer the latter.